# Correlating Firestore indexes to slugs in a webapp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'd like my web app router slugs to correspond to my Firestore documents data.

For example:

```
www.mysite.com/restaurants/burger-king
/restaurants               <- Firestore Collection
/restaurants/mcdonalds     <- Firestore Document
/restaurants/burger-king   <- Firestore Document
```

This is easy enough, as I can assign the name as a slug-friendly UID in Firestore. The difficulty arises with CRUD functionality. I need to be able to *rename* my item titles, but Firestore does not permit you to rename indexes, which is the issue I'm facing.

One SO solution I saw was to delete the old record and creates a new one at the updated index. That's problematic for me, because sub-collections would be hard to transfer from the client side.

Are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: As far as I can see there are no subcollections in the data structure you shared. Also: can you explain why the delete-under-old-name-and-add-under-new-name would be hard?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to identify a document by its ID.  If you're able to ensure uniqueness of a document field value, you could instead query a collection for an ID value in a known field, then use the results of that query to satisfy your REST API.  Then, you can change the value of that document field as often as you want, in order to satisfy required changes to the public API.